# Is there a way to query the HTML in the Ace code editor?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-parsing, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

When I'm editing HTML in the ace editor, is there a way to query that HTML in a simple way? With selectors?

```
[fake-html-dom].querySelectorAll("A").length
```

I read that when you use jQuery `$('<html code>')` the html gets inserted to the real DOM, I want to avoid actually running the HTML it in the window/iframe.

Would also be nice to be able to modify the found elements in the editor directly (like custom highlighting).

Comment: would you explain what do you exactly want to do or is that all about `to query that HTML in a simple way`!?

Comment: I think my answer would meet your need. check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a fake html document object like this:

```
var docImpl = document.implementation;
var fakeDoc = docImpl.createHTMLDocument("myhtml"/*it is just a title*/);
```

as you use a Ace html editor first you should read the html string from the editor, then extract the body content and finally insert it to the fake body. these are your steps to take:

```
//Ace usually uses ace_text-layer as the classname for the html string part
var htmlContent = document.querySelector(".ace_text-layer").innerText;
//you can also change this part if it didn't work, depends on your Ace version
```

now you should extract the body content, if it has `<html>` or `<body>` tags in it:

```
var pattern = /<body[^>]*>((.|[\n\r])*)<\/body>/im;
var array_matches = pattern.exec(htmlContent);
var extractedContent = array_matches[1];
```

then insert it to the fake body

```
fakeDoc.body.innerHTML = extractedContent;
```

and finally do any desired query you might need:

```
fakeDoc.querySelectorAll("A").length
```

Comment: wow, hard working man, great answer. I learned a few new tricks :)

Comment: you're welcome, I really like innovative questions, the idea of querying thru the real time html is one of them, no matter you know all the stuff or not.